# Injective linear function between $ \left( \mathbb{Z}_p \right)^n $ and $ \left( \mathbb{Z}_p \right)^m $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that a sufficient condition for a linear function between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ to be injective is that the associated $m \times n $ matrix A has $ \text{rank}(A)=min(m,n)$.
Now I am working with linear function between $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p^m$; that condition no longer holds; for example the matrix 
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad $
has rank 2 but (I think) the function in not injective because $ A \cdot {A^T} $ is
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0  \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad $
and it is not invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I mean with p=3.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\rank}{\mathrm{rank}}$
It's not true that a linear function $A:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is injective if $\rank(A)=\min(m,n)$. What is required is that $\rank(A)=n$. This is still true for linear functions $\mathbb Z_p^n\to\mathbb Z_p^m$. Your example cannot be injective because it is a linear function $\mathbb{Z}_p^3\to\mathbb{Z}_p^2$, and rank $3$ would be required.

A linear function is injective if and only if its kernel (null space) is trivial, and this is the same as saying that the rank is equal to the dimension of the domain. This is a general theorem of linear algebra and does not depend on the specific coefficient field, as long as it's the same in the domain and codomain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I wish to precise my context: in Coding theory we use, for example, a $2 \times 3$ matrix for a linear code $ f:\left( \mathbb{Z}_p \right)^2 \to \left( \mathbb{Z}_p  \right)^3 $ because we usually multiply $\mathbf{x} \in \left( \mathbb{Z}_p \right)^2 $ by a $2 \times 3$ matrix, and not viceversa.

So in $ \mathbb{Z}_3 $ the matrix 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad $
maps $\mathbf{x}=[1,2]$ to $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}A=[0,1,2]$.

My question, more precisely, is: the function is injective as $ \text{rank}(A)=2$; in which way could I come back from $\mathbf{y}$ to $\mathbf{x}$?
I cannot use 
$\mathbf{x}G=\mathbf{y} \Rightarrow 
\mathbf{x}G G^T=\mathbf{y} G^T \Rightarrow
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y} G^T (GG^T)^{-1} $
as $GG^T=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0  \\
0 & 2  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad $ is not invertible in $ \mathbb{Z}_3 $.
Thanks